# Why do I get UnknownPluginException when trying to use a custom Kotlin complier plugin in Gradle?

Tags: gradle, kotlin, gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have created a custom Kotlin compiler plugin for Gradle.  It was inspired by [kotlin-allopen](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/tree/master/plugins/allopen) [(2)](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html#all-open-compiler-plugin) and [sample-kotlin-compiler-plugin](https://github.com/Takhion/sample-kotlin-compiler-plugin), and is supposed to make all Kotlin classes non-final.

The problem is, I'm unable to use it in my projects, I only get the following:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin with id 'no.synth.kotlin.plugins.kotlin-really-allopen' not found.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.apply(DefaultPluginManager.java:131)
```

I have tried both the "new" plugin syntax:

```
plugins {
  id "no.synth.kotlin.plugins.kotlin-really-allopen" version "0.1"
}
```

.. and the old one:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenLocal()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath "no.synth.kotlin.plugins:kotlin-really-allopen:0.1" 
  }
}

apply plugin: "kotlin-really-allopen" // I've tried "no.synth.kotlin.plugins.kotlin-really-allopen" as well
```

So what am I doing wrong?  Here's the plugin: https://github.com/henrik242/kotlin-really-allopen

EDIT: I have updated the repository with an example app and a README.md to easily reproduce the problem.

Comment: where do you have it deployed? `mavenLocal()`? or a private `nexus` repo? or to the `gradlePluginsPortal`?

Comment: I have it deployed to mavenLocal. Gradle finds it, because it fails earlier if I add a typo to the classcast definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Gradle plugin doesn't seem to contain any entry under `META-INF/gradle-plugins`.

Gradle requires that every plugin ID is mapped to the implementation class, and this mapping is stored in `META-INF/gradle-plugins` resources.

To map the plugin ID `kotlin-really-allopen`, you would need a resource file
`src/main/resources/META-INF/gradle-plugins/kotlin-really-allopen.properties`.

See: [Wiring for a custom plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html#example_wiring_for_a_custom_plugin)

You can also use the [Gradle Plugin Development Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_gradle_plugin.html), which automatically generates these entries from the build script DSL.

---

Also, your repository doesn't seem to contain an actual Gradle plugin implementation, there's only the part that the compiler needs to load. For an example that contains the Gradle part too, take a look at [kevinmost/debuglog](https://github.com/kevinmost/debuglog).

Comment: I looked at the `kotlin-allopen` plugin jar contents, and it doesn't have `META-INF/gradle-plugins`. Any idea why that works? Ref. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-allopen/1.3.30

Comment: @neu242, I've just downloaded the JAR an it *does* have `META-INF/gradle-plugins` with four entries in it, `kotlin-allopen.properties`, `kotlin-spring.properties`, `org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.allopen.properties`, `org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.spring.properties`.

Comment: @neu242, the source for that module is here by the way: https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/tree/master/libraries/tools/kotlin-allopen

Comment: Wow, thanks! Really appreciated.  I somehow had a jar locally without those entries, probably from when I tried building from `plugins/allopen` (not `libraries/tools/kotlin-allopen`).

Comment: You were also failing to actually check your mavenLocal. You can see the pr I made in your repo to see how to do that. https://github.com/henrik242/kotlin-really-allopen/pull/1/files

Answer (score 0):

Move `apply plugin: "kotlin-really-allopen"` in your `build.gradle` module app on top

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I'm having it in the exact same place as I earlier had the `kotlin-allopen` plug-in

Comment: I have updated the repository with an example app and a README.md to easily reproduce the problem.  Feel like taking a look? :)